# Add app to Fabric console (with Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric

I have a new android App which I successfully connected with Firebase. I have also successfully enabled Crashlytics (via Firebase). To my surprise, I found out, that Firebase does not have Crashlytics Beta yet. However, I'd like to distribute test versions of the app via Crashlytics Beta.

So I tried to add the App to the Fabric (not Firebase) console as well, but the Android Studio Fabric Plugin is not detecting it and it does not appear in the Fabric Console.

So my question is twofold:
Can I somehow distribute the test app via Firebase?
If not, how can I add the App to the Fabric console as well? Note, there was no prior integration of fabric, I just integrated fabric via firebase directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fabric plugin available in android studio. Install that.
Once you sign in, you can choose for crashlytics and it will auto integrate your app with fabric.

Then for checking crashes, you can go to fabric.io console and check it.
check if you have done following :

In build.gradle

```
     repositories {maven { URL 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }}
     dependencies {classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'}
     apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

In Application class

```
     Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics())
```

In Manifest:

```
     <meta-data
      android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
      android:value="your key"/>
```

Comment: That's what I am using. It just says that it waits for the app to start

Comment: Updated my comment.

Comment: 1.25.4, but yes

Comment: The key was wrong due to flavors. I had to add it and then remove it (because firebase does not need it). Thanks

Comment: Ah. Cool. Anytime

Comment: Update for future me... If the app has flavors, publishing a second flavor to Crashlytics Beta is not possible until you temporarily disable the google-services plugin (needed by firebase). Fabric (for some strange reason) does not allow to add a second app until you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create app in fabric crashlytics
and follow this link
https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

after that crash your app.
Now you can see your app is automatically added in fabric crashlatics console

Comment: I did that. I see the crash within the Firebase console, but I don't see the app in the Fabric console